# Gulp not found, also not allowing to install

Tags: npm, gulp

I have this come back in the terminal. Did have gulp previously, so not sure why it's not being found when inputting "gulp -v"

```
$ npm install -g gulp
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/applesandoranges0609/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, if I put "npm gulp -v" I get a version number back. Confused though, if installed globally should't I only have to "gulp -v"

Answer (score 0):

To install the Gulp command line utility you have to run

`npm i -g gulp-cli`

not just `gulp`. That's the dependency that should be added to projects so you can run gulp from the projects `node_modules` folder instead.